# Блокируется доступ к домену после ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache

Использую ubuntu 16.04
Сначала apache ругается на .htaccess c такой ошибкой

```
RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-d' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

Гугл говорит, что в .htaccess нужно убрать [NS], НО!
После этой ошибки доступ к домену блокируется и перенаправляется на https с ошибкой ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. То есть если даже удалить .htaccess и весь коталог сайта, оставив только index.php и echo('hellow'). Доступа не будет и не будет ничего писать в логи, даже если потом выключить локальный сервер, то всё равно ошибка также будет висеть в браузере.
Использовал как просто локальный LAMP, сейчас использую сборку docker https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp
При всём при этом сайт сейчас работает нормально на хостинге и работал нормально до этого на windows open server.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в собственной глупости,постепенное включение правил в .htaccess и замена портов при каждом блокировании домена помогли установить проблему. В .htaccess был 301 редирект, который хорошо и правильно работал на хостинге и почему то игнорировался Open Server - linux же делал ровно то, что ему быол сказано, по этому хром просто запоминал что страница преремещена навсегда и как бы "блокировал" мне localhost.